# Compiling Errors after creating Registration Page [React / Java]

Tags: java, node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I keep getting these /lib errors when trying to compile. I added the route and created the .css file. Im very new to react and javascript as a whole and unsure on if i need to install any modules etc. Or am i missing anything

```
Error in ./src/containers/Signup.js
Module not found: ../components/LoaderButton in C:\Users\AH\Desktop\notes-app-client\src\containers

 @ ./src/containers/Signup.js 25:20-57

Error in ./src/containers/Signup.js
Module not found: ../libs/contextLib in C:\Users\AH\Desktop\notes-app-client\src\containers

 @ ./src/containers/Signup.js 29:18-47

Error in ./src/containers/Signup.js
Module not found: ../libs/hooksLib in C:\Users\AH\Desktop\notes-app-client\src\containers

 @ ./src/containers/Signup.js 31:16-43

Error in ./src/containers/Signup.js
Module not found: ../libs/errorLib in C:\Users\AH\Desktop\notes-app-client\src\containers
```

Comment: its seems that you are providing the wrong path to a component, provide your code as well so that we may check

Comment: import LoaderButton from "../components/LoaderButton";
import { useAppContext } from "../libs/contextLib";
import { useFormFields } from "../libs/hooksLib";
import { onError } from "../libs/errorLib";

Comment: Im not sure if that is the correct location for the libs. Or if i need to install the libs and they are missing